# Why does a non pivot column have a free variable in a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Unknowns in non-pivot columns are assumed to a certain value .Why should we assume a value to a free variable ? Why shouldn't we assume a value to a basic variable if free variables are found?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried to see what happens for small examples?

Comment: In small examples, non pivot columns of matrices in reduced row echelon form have free variables